# How to pass ID value from Jquery DatePicker editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

This calender picker allows me to log the date value picked, but I need to pass the ID value in the tags as well, but I can't get it to work.

PLEASE HELP!!!

Here is where we show the date value, and the calendar sets its value, but I need to pass along the ID "12003" value as well.

```
<span class="editable" id="12003">2014-09-01</span>
```

This the first JS file

```
$( document ).ready( function() {

  var date = $( '.editable' );

  date.editable(
    function( value, settings ) {
      date.html( value );


      //////////////// Need to pass the ID value to here
      console.log(id);
      console.log(value);

    },
    {
      type: 'datepicker',
      datepicker: {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd', 
        numberOfMonths: 1       
      }   
    }
  );

} );
```

And here is the second JS file

```
// add :focus selector
jQuery.expr[':'].focus = function( elem ) {
  return elem === document.activeElement && ( elem.type || elem.href );
};

$.editable.addInputType( 'datepicker', {

    /* create input element */
    element: function( settings, original ) {
      var form = $( this ),
          input = $( '<input />' );
      input.attr( 'autocomplete','off' );
      form.append( input );
      return input;
    },

    /* attach jquery.ui.datepicker to the input element */
    plugin: function( settings, original ) {
      var form = this,
          input = form.find( "input" );

      // Don't cancel inline editing onblur to allow clicking datepicker
      settings.onblur = 'nothing';

      datepicker = {
        onSelect: function() {
          // clicking specific day in the calendar should
          // submit the form and close the input field
          form.submit();
        },

        onClose: function() {
          setTimeout( function() {
            if ( !input.is( ':focus' ) ) {
              original.reset( form );
            } else {
              form.submit();
            }
          }, 150 );
        }
      };

      if (settings.datepicker) {
        jQuery.extend(datepicker, settings.datepicker);
      }
      input.datepicker(datepicker);
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is the only datepicker on your webpage, you can access it like:

```
$('.editable').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as:

```
console.log($(this).attr('id'));
```